# In C#, can you put an Or in an "where" interface constraint?

Tags: c#, generics, interface

if i have this code:

```
public interface IJobHelper
{
    List<T> FilterwithinOrg<T>(IEnumerable<T> entities) where T : IFilterable;
}
```

is there anything that support doing something like this:

```
public interface IJobHelper
{
    List<T> FilterwithinOrg<T>(IEnumerable<T> entities) where T : IFilterable or ISemiFilterable
}
```

so it will accept anything that supports one of two interfaces.  I am basically trying to create an overload.

Comment: Why not make a generic filterable class, then inherit that class with more specific filterable classes. You can then use the where clause with the generic filterable class and constrain to multiple classes.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3679562/generic-methods-and-method-overloading

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The language doesn't support 'oring' together interfaces/classes in the `where` clause.

You need will need to state them separately with different method names so the signatures are different.

```
public interface IJobHelper
{
    List<T> FilterwithinOrg<T>(IEnumerable<T> entities) 
        where T : IFilterable
    List<T> SemiFilterwithinOrg<T>(IEnumerable<T> entities) 
        where T : ISemiFilterable
}
```

Alternatively you can implement a common interface on both interfaces. This is not the same thing as above though as it may require a cast when you receive the object back if you need a specific interface that isn't contained within `IBaseFilterable`.

```
public interface IBaseFilterable { }
public interface IFilterable : IBaseFilterable { }
public interface ISemiFilterable : IBaseFilterable { }

public interface IJobHelper
{
    List<T> FilterwithinOrg<T>(IEnumerable<T> entities)
        where T : IBaseFilterable
}
```

I don't know the context but the above is probably what you're looking for.

Comment: I tried the first thing by just listing it twice in the interface with different Where constraints but i get "same method is already declared" error . . any ideas?

Comment: Ah true, I'll fix the answer. You'll need to give them different names

Answer (score 3):

As far as I know, you can use *AND* logic not *OR*.

**AND** (in this case, *T* must be child of *IFilterable* **and** *ISemiFilterable*)

```
public interface IJobHelper
{
    List<T> FilterwithinOrg<T>(IEnumerable<T> entities) where T : IFilterable, ISemiFilterable
}
```

Answer (score 2):

No, the language does not support that.

Answer (score 2):

The easy way I would say, is if both your interfaces where children of the same parent interface.

```
public interface IFilterable { }

public interface IFullyFilterable : IFilterable { }

public interface ISemiFilterable : IFilterable { }

... where T : IFilterable { }
```

Comment: This is not **OR** logic. If you have class which is child of *ISemiFilterable*, then it means, this class is also child of *IFilterable*.

Comment: @VanoMaisuradze Yes? And the result would be the same?

Comment: Which result? What you wrote, isn't OR. It's AND

Comment: @VanoMaisuradze Of course not! If `T` is `ISemiFilterable`, it's not `IFullyFilterable`. So, it's not an AND.

Answer (score 0):

You can just add another empty base interface that both these interfaces are derived from...

```
 interface baseInterface {}
 interface IFilterable: baseInterface {}
 interface ISemiFilterable: baseInterface {}
```

and then demand that the type in the generic type constraint be the base interface

```
 List<T> FilterwithinOrg<T>(IEnumerable<T> entities) where T : baseInterface
```

The only downside is the compiler will not allow you to use methods from either of the derived interfaces without casting...