# Call generic method in c#

Tags: c#

Consider this code:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
   Get<Student>(new Student());
    System.Console.Read();
}

public static void Get<T>(T person)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Generic function");
}
public static void Get(Person person)
{
    person.Show();
}
```

This my Person Class:

```
class Person
{
    public void Show()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("I am person");
    }
}
class Student : Person
{
    public new void Show()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("I am Student");
    }
}
```

I call `Get` and pass student to the method.Like this:

```
 Get<Student>(new Student());
```

So i get this: `Generic function`.But when i call `Get` like this:

```
 Get(new Student());
```

I expect this`Get(Person person)`to be called.but again call:`Get<T>(T person)`.
Why Compiler has this behavior?

Comment: Look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3679562/generic-methods-and-method-overloading), the question is basically the same

Comment: The exact rules for overload precedence are complicated and in the specification: but I suspect it is actually calling `Get<Student>(Student)` - which is an exact match; `Get(Person)` is *not* an exact match because you are passing a Student, not a Person

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I can refer you the Jon Skeet's book C# in Depth (second edition for now), a chapter number  9.4.4. I altered the text to fit in you situation.

> **Picking the right overloaded method**
>
> At this point, the compiler considers the conversion from Student to
>   Student, and from Student to Person. A conversion from any type to
>   itself is defined to be better than any conversion to a different
>   type, so the Get(T x) with T as a Student method is better than
>   Get(Person y) for this particular call.

There is a slighly more explanation in the book and I can at least strongly recommend you to read it thoroughly.