# Disambiguate two equally specific, identical signatures (generic methods)

Tags: c#, .net, generics, overloading, overload-resolution

Consider the following class:

```
public class TwoWayMap<T1, T2>
{
    public T2 Get(T1 x)
    {
        throw new System.NotImplementedException();
    }

    public T1 Get(T2 x)
    {
        throw new System.NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

If T1 and T2 are different types and we call `Get`, then the compiler knows which one we mean.

```
var map1 = new TwoWayMap<int, string>();
map1.Get("hello");
map1.Get(5);
```

However, if the types are equal, then the two methods share the same signature. And in terms of overload resolution, they are equally specific (compared to, say, [a generic vs a non-generic parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3679562)). Therefore, we cannot call the method unambiguously.

```
var map2 = new TwoWayMap<int, int>();
map2.Get(5);
```

> Compiler Error CS0121: The call is ambiguous between the following
>   methods or properties: 'TwoWayMap.Get(T1)' and 'TwoWayMap.Get(T2)'

Of course, we can (and should) avoid this issue by not using equal types or by providing dedicated `Get1` and `Get2` methods, but I am wondering: Is there some way in C# or .NET to disambiguate this? Is it possible to call `map2.Get()`?

Comment: Only through reflection, but then the choice is arbitrary - there's no way to distinguish one method over the other.

Comment: I suggest just using different names for the `Get`s. It would be much clearer as to what the code is actually doing when someone quickly glances at it.

Comment: But the compiler already guarantees this can't happen, so why ask if there's another way the compiler can guarantee it won't happen?

Answer (score 1):

If I updated that API to use `GetSource` and `GetTarget` I would have no idea which one Get(5) would be, How is the compiler supposed to know?

Although looking a little closer at the question I think you could use `GetMethods()` and just invoke the second one returned.

Answer (score 0):

you can do something like this

```
interface IGetter1<T1,T2>
{
    T2 Get(T1 x);
}

interface IGetter2<T1, T2>
{
    T2 Get(T1 x);
}
public class TwoWayMap<T1, T2> : IGetter1<T1,T2>,IGetter2<T2,T1>
{
    public T2 Get(T1 x)
    {
        throw new System.NotImplementedException();
    }

    public T1 Get(T2 x)
    {
        throw new System.NotImplementedException();
    }
}

var map1 = new TwoWayMap<int, int>();
        var map2 =(IGetter1<int,int>) map1;
        var map3 = (IGetter2<int, int>) map1;
     //   map2.Get(5);
        map3.Get(5);
```

Comment: @Servy Yes it is much cleaner and better than using reflection and reflection has some performance implication...

Comment: I didn't say anything about using reflection.

Comment: @servy reflection was suggested by someone as one of the approach...I was just pointing out that....I don't have enough reps yet to comment on that thread directly. :)

Comment: Both of them are very poor solutions, and neither of them should be used.  Why you've decided to tell me that your solution is a tad better than another person's very poor solution, while still much, much worse than the solution *I* mentioned is beyond me.